# Calling Webservice from Apex class, getting 302 response error

Tags: apex, callout, rest-service

I have the below code trying to make a HTTP callout from a APEX class. The response I get back is

```
System.HttpResponse[Status=Moved Temporarily, StatusCode=302]
```

My class is

```
public with sharing class soapServiceApexClass {
    @future(callout=true)  
    @AuraEnabled  
        public static void createSOAPWebSevice(Integer x, Integer y){
                partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap myPartnerSoap = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
                partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult partnerLoginResult = myPartnerSoap.login('username', 'pwd');
                system.debug('partnerLoginResult'+partnerLoginResult);
                soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.SessionHeader_element webserviceSessionHeader = new soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.SessionHeader_element();
                webserviceSessionHeader.sessionId = partnerLoginResult.sessionId;
                soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.MyWebService mySOAPWebservice = new soapSforceComSchemasClassMywebservi.MyWebService();
                mySOAPWebservice.SessionHeader = webserviceSessionHeader;
                Integer z = mySOAPWebservice.Mul(1,2);
                system.debug ('z========='+z);
        }
        @AuraEnabled(continuation=true)
        public static map<String, Object> sendRequest(integer x,integer y) {
            map<String, Object> mapJsonData = new map<String, Object>();
           

        Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
        string strResponse;
         con.continuationMethod='getResponse';
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
       httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
        httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://datasirpicnat-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/');
        //loc : https://datasirpicnat-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/
        try {  
            
            Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest); 
            system.debug('res body=========='+httpResponse.getBody()); 
            System.debug('httpResponse'+httpResponse);
            boolean redirect = false;
            
   
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() >=300 && httpResponse.getStatusCode() <= 307 && httpResponse.getStatusCode() != 306) {
            do {
                redirect = false; 
                String loc = httpResponse.getHeader('Location');
                system.debug('loc =========='+loc); 
                if(loc == null) {
                    redirect = false;
                    continue;
                }
                httpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint(loc);
                req.setMethod('GET');
                HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
                if(httpResponse.getStatusCode() != 500) { 
                    if(res.getStatusCode() >=300 && res.getStatusCode() <= 307 && res.getStatusCode() != 306) {
                        redirect= true;
                    }
                    system.debug('Inside this if');
                    
                }
                system.debug('body of the 302 res is'+ res.getBody());
                if (res.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
            
                    strResponse = res.getBody();  
                    system.debug('strResponse====='+strResponse);
                }   
            } while (redirect && Limits.getCallouts() != Limits.getLimitCallouts());
         
        }
        
      system.debug('================================================');
     if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
            
                strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();  
                system.debug('strResponse====='+strResponse);
            } 
            else {  
                throw new CalloutException(httpResponse.getBody());  
            } 
        
     
    system.debug('after callouts ========= '+httpResponse.getBody());
}
        
    catch(Exception ex) {  
        throw ex;  
    }  
  
  if(!String.isBlank(strResponse)) {
        mapJsonData = (map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse);
        System.debug('mapJsonData ===> '+mapJsonData);
        
    }
      return mapJsonData;
  
}       
  
}
```

also tried to handle the statuscode 302 in my class
exception System.CalloutException and not displaying any message same status code remains as 302 in developer console

Comment: You shouldn't be getting any 302 status. You need to use the full, correct endpoint to access the API.

Comment: I think 302 is returned by Salesforce when you're redirected to another page, for example when based on user's preferences you're redirected from Lightning to Classic.  What is your use case to handling 3xx codes?